# Encountering problem when setting a Selenium proxy

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

When I try to crawl the information on maoyan_film, I meet a problem with how to set a selenium proxy. Because my ip is forbidden by Maoyan.
I set the proxy of selenium, but it always error, which I do not know how to solve.

Here are two errors. Every time I try to test ip, it always displays this. The href of the web shows `'data;,'`, I don't understand.
[image]
[image]
The message1:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: > net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED
> (Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.138)
> Website:Chrome
> Here is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

with open('ipaddress.txt', 'r') as f:
    iplist = f.readlines()
    for i in iplist:
        ip=i.strip('\n')
        driver_path = r'\chromedriver.exe'
        service = Service(driver_path)
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % ip)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
        driver.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
        if 'origin' in driver.page_source:
            print(ip)
```

I want to know how can I repair my code.

Comment: what's inside the file 'ipaddress.txt' ?

Comment: `data;` is just shown when the webdriver starts. It' just the default

Comment: 'ipaddress.txt ' is a place where put free ip address and port.

Answer (score 0):

Free Proxies usually are slow or don't work at all

You might consider buying some cheap ones (residential), for example from asocks

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a proxy with Selenium can be a bit tricky, but no worries, I got you. First, make sure you've got the right proxy info (host, port, username, and password), and then try this example with your own proxy details:
python

```
from selenium import webdriver

proxy = "host:port"
username = "your_username"
password = "your_password"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# this adds the proxy extension to Chrome
chrome_options.add_extension("proxy.zip")

capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="your_chrome_driver_path", desired_capabilities=capabilities)

# navigate to a URL to fill in the proxy credentials
driver.get(f"http://{username}:{password}@{proxy}")

# now you can navigate to the desired website
driver.get("https://www.maoyan.com/")
```

But before you go that route, it might be worth considering using a different proxy service, especially if you're facing constant bans and connection issues. I've had a good experience with [SOAX](https://soax.com/) – they've got a large pool of IPs and cool geo-targeting features. Might be worth checking out. Good luck!